# PHP to read button value from dynamically generated code from an ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some PHP that is generated dynamically from a previous call to an ajax function.

The code generates a list of information using a while loop so the snippet below code be 1 to infinity depending on what the MYSQL query returns.

```
echo "<div class='col-md-3'><button class='btn btn-primary-orange    mid' type='submit' id='searchbutton' value='" . $mydata["MyID"] . "' name='jid'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart' aria-hidden='true'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Save Me</button></div>";
```

When the Save Me button is clicked I want to read the value of the button using php so I can save it to a database.

When the button is clicked I am calling some JQUERY so I know the value can be read. Value us a unique ID.

```
$(document).on('click', '.mid', function(){
alert($(this).attr("value"));
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxlistings.php",
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data: $("#formID").serialize(),
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#jdisplaylisting').html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Sorry, there was a problem!: " + error);
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(error);
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I thought I could use the standard PHP

```
$newvalue = $_POST['jid']
```

to read the value associated with the button but it refuses to work.

I am guessing it is to do with dynamically created element?

Comment: Buttons aren't included in `serialize()`, because it doesn't know which button was pushed.

Comment: It has nothing to do with it being dynamically created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `serialize()` method doesn't know which button was pushed, so it doesn't include any buttons in the result. You'll need to do it yourself in the code.

```
data: this.name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value) + '&' + $("#formID").serialize(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the value in a hidden field within your form

```
<input type='hidden' value='<?= $mydata["MyID"] ?>' name='my_field'>
```

When you serialize and submit your form, the value will be sent to PHP

```
$newvalue = $_POST['my_field'];
```